# Can't understand this GCD algorithm

Tags: solidity, algorithm, modulo

I was trying to get the GCD of two numbers. This function I saw on github works fine but I have a confusion here.

The function :

```
   function _gcd(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 _a = a;//65
        uint256 _b = b;//784
        uint256 temp;//0
        while (_b > 0) {
            temp = _b;//784
            _b = _a % _b; // % is remainder 0
            _a = temp;//784
        }
        return _a;
    }
```

The confusion is in this line:

```
                _b = _a % _b; // % is remainder
```

So when we modulo a smaller number with a large one it gives out zero.

In the case of this function, even if I pass the smaller number at uint a and the larger number at uint b, it gives out the correct GCD. How is it working?
I am confused about when we pass a smaller number as `a` then in the first loop the `_b` variable will be zero and `_a` will be returned and it won't be the correct GCD, but it is returning the correct GCD.

Like how is `a % b` giving out the same answer as `b % a`

The GitHub code: https://gist.github.com/3esmit/8c0a63f17f2f2448cc1576eb27fe5910

Please let me know if I was able to convey the problem. I will elaborate more on this if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do large%small it gives remainder which can be 0 if it is fully divided but if we do small%large it only gonna give us small. Suppose
if _a=65 and _b=784 then

1. first loop temp=784, _b=65, _a=temp
2. second loop temp=65, _b=4 , _a=temp
3. third loop temp=4,  _b=1 , _a=temp
4. fourth loop temp=1, _b=0, _a=temp